# Exact solution of Qubit Decoherence using Transfer Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, mathematics, decoherence

I'm going through a particular paper on decoherence: [Exact Solution of Qubit Decoherence models by a transfer matrix method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0511021v2.pdf)

I'm having trouble understanding a particular step in the mathematics involved. I'm not able to understand how equation (4) was obtained from the equation in Fig: 1.

Fig 1:

> [image: Fig 1]

Equation (4):

> [image: Equation (4)]

It is told in the paper that "They key to the method is to compute and iterate the superoperators..".

It would be a great help if someone could give me a hint on what is going on. I would like to try it out myself and thus, I'm not expecting any complete answers. Thankyou.

Comment: Please include *all* information relevant to your question in the post. It's your job to take the relevant information from the paper and type it here. It is not the job of the reader to do that work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't do it when I posted the question. I'm indeed doing that now. The delay is because I'm not comfortable with Latex. I will put up pictures of the relevant equations soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case of bad labeling: the $i$,$j$ labels in Fig.1 and Eqs.(4-5) have different meaning. In addition, subscript 1 was dropped on all $B$'s in Eq.(5). Other than that, it's straightforward algebra:

Start by rewriting the final result of Fig.(1) in the familiar operator-product form, expand, and rearrange:
$$
\overline{\left[ E \cos(B_1\tau) - i {\hat B_1}\cdot{\vec \sigma}\sin(B_1\tau)\right]{\vec \sigma}(0) \left[ E \cos(B_1\tau) + i {\hat B_1}\cdot{\vec \sigma}\sin(B_1\tau)\right]} = \\
= \overline{\cos^2(B_1\tau)} \;{\vec \sigma}(0)  + i {\vec \sigma}(0) \left[\overline{\cos(B_1\tau)\sin(B_1\tau){\hat B_1} } \cdot{\vec \sigma}\right] -  \\
- i \left[ \overline{\cos(B_1\tau)\sin(B_1\tau){\hat B_1} } \cdot{\vec \sigma} \right] {\vec \sigma}(0) + \overline{\sin^2(B_1\tau)\left[{\hat B_1} \cdot{\vec \sigma}\right] {\vec \sigma}(0) \left[{\hat B_1}  \cdot{\vec \sigma} \right] }=\\
= \overline{\cos^2(B_1\tau)} \;{\vec \sigma}(0) + i \sum_i{\left(\overline{\cos(B_1\tau)\sin(B_1\tau)B_{1,i} } \right) \left[ {\vec \sigma}(0)\sigma_i - \sigma_i  {\vec \sigma}(0)\right]} + 
\sum_{i,j}{\left( \overline{\sin^2(B_1\tau)B_{1,i} B_{1,j}  } \right) \sigma_i \;{\vec \sigma}(0)\; \sigma_j}
$$
Now identify
$$
I_0 = \overline{\cos^2(B_1\tau)} 
$$
$$
 I_i = \overline{B_{1,i} \cos(B_1\tau)\sin(B_1\tau)  } 
$$
$$
I_{ij} = \overline{B_{1,i} B_{1,j} \sin^2(B_1\tau) } 
$$
and tidy up:
$$
\overline{\left[ E \cos(B_1\tau) - i {\hat B_1}\cdot{\vec \sigma}\sin(B_1\tau)\right]{\vec \sigma}(0) \left[ E \cos(B_1\tau) + i {\hat B_1}\cdot{\vec \sigma}\sin(B_1\tau)\right]} = 
$$
$$
= I_0 \; {\vec \sigma}(0) + i \sum_i {I_i \left[ {\vec \sigma}(0)\sigma_i - \sigma_i  {\vec \sigma}(0)\right]} + \sum_{i,j}{I_{ij}\;\sigma_i\; {\vec \sigma}(0)\; \sigma_j }
$$

Comment: Thank you. This has made it much more clearer. Though, I should have asked this before asking the above question I have a doubt regarding the action of the unitary operator itself. In the Heisenberg picture we have time dependence on operators and the operator evolves according to $\sigma(t)=hermitian conjugate(U)\sigma(0)U$..so thinking in the matrix form..we have three 2*2 matrices getting multiplied. But in the above paper we have  $\vec\sigma(t)=hermitian conjugate(U)\vec\sigma(0)U$..which is a 2*2 matrix * a 3*1 matrix * a 2*2 matrix. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: $\vec \sigma$ is short for a vector of three 2x2 matrices, ${\vec \sigma} = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3)$.